# Android App crashing when I split MainActivity into several classes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I'm just a beginner in android development. Recently I'm developing an app which converts a unit between other units. The code was growing very large & it became eventually cumbersome to maintain and finding, fixing bugs. So, I tried to split the MainActivity.java into other classes, but now the apps keeping crashing. Android Studio can build and run the project, but it no longer runs on my device.

`MainActivity.java` file contains

```
package com.gazzali.spinitmeow;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner spinnerMainChoice, spinnerInputChoice, spinnerOutputChoice;

    EditText getInputValueID;
    double inputValue;

    TextView outputValue;

    Button buttonConvert;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* ------------ Main code Starts Here ----------------*/

        /* Main conversion Type choice with Spinner (Drop Down menu)*/
        spinnerMainChoice = findViewById(R.id.spinnerIDMainChoice);
        // [IMPORTANT] Set Spinner Click Listener
        spinnerMainChoice.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterMainChoice = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.MainChoices_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapterMainChoice.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinnerMainChoice.setAdapter(adapterMainChoice);

        /* Input Conversion type choice with Spinner */
        spinnerInputChoice = findViewById(R.id.spinnerIDInputChoice);
        spinnerInputChoice.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        /* Output Conversion type choice with Spinner */

        spinnerOutputChoice = findViewById(R.id.spinnerIDOutputChoice);
        spinnerOutputChoice.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        /* for input and output fields */
        getInputValueID = findViewById(R.id.editTextIDInputValue);
        String inputValueString = getInputValueID.getText().toString();
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(inputValueString))
        {
            try
            {
                inputValue = Double.parseDouble(inputValueString);
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        outputValue = findViewById(R.id.textViewIDOutputValue);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. retrieve the selected item
        String selectedMainChoice = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        Log.i("Selected", selectedMainChoice);
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected: " + selectedMainChoice, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

/* This is where I made the separation ; previously the contents inside the spinnerSelects's setInputOutSpinner()
        was inside the MainActivity as a method */

        spinnerSelects spinnerSelects = new spinnerSelects();
        spinnerSelects.setInputOutputSpinners(selectedMainChoice);

    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }

}
```

`spinnerSelects.java` file contanis:

```
package com.gazzali.spinitmeow;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class spinnerSelects extends MainActivity{

    protected void setInputOutputSpinners(String selectedMainChoice) {
        switch (selectedMainChoice)
        {
            case "Length": {
                spinnerInputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LengthChoices_array)));

                spinnerOutputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LengthChoices_array)));
            }
            break;

            case "Temperature": {
                spinnerInputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.TemperatureChoices_array)));

                spinnerOutputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.TemperatureChoices_array)));
            }
            break;

            case "Weight": {
                spinnerInputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.WeightChoices_array)));

                spinnerOutputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.WeightChoices_array)));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The Logcat shows this traces,which is much alien to me.

```
2019-07-20 19:55:12.757 18958-18958/com.gazzali.spinitmeow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.gazzali.spinitmeow, PID: 18958
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:91)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResourcesInternal(ContextThemeWrapper.java:127)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:121)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:543)
    at com.gazzali.spinitmeow.spinnerSelects.setInputOutputSpinners(spinnerSelects.java:13)
    at com.gazzali.spinitmeow.MainActivity.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:83)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:944)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:933)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:53)
    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:898)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
2019-07-20 19:55:12.787 18958-18958/com.gazzali.spinitmeow I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18958 SIG: 9
```

> at com.gazzali.spinitmeow.spinnerSelects.setInputOutputSpinners(spinnerSelects.java:13)
>           at com.gazzali.spinitmeow.MainActivity.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:83)

these two lines have blue underlined whereas others in red.

Can someone please tell me where I need to fixe bugs so my doesn't crashes anymore?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack traces associated with your crashes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this If you do not understand what the stack traces are telling you, edit your question and post the stack trace that comes from running the version of the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

For solving your current **NullPointerException** problem,

pass your activity context to your spinnerSelects desired method

```
spinnerSelects.setInputOutputSpinners(MainActivity.this,selectedMainChoice);
```

and in this method use that activity to getResources

```
protected void setInputOutputSpinners(Activity activity, String selectedMainChoice) {
        switch (selectedMainChoice)
        {
            case "Length": {
                spinnerInputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LengthChoices_array)));

                spinnerOutputChoice.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LengthChoices_array)));
            }
            break;


        }
    }
```

> Hope it will solve your problem but in my opinion, your this code is
>   not good. you can improve it.
>
> if my solution did not work, don't extend MainActivity and keep the 
>   **spinnerSelects** as just a Java class and pass `Spinner spinnerInputChoice` variables
>   to the desired class methods.

Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not extend any `Activity` class in any other class. Instances of `Activity` classes would be created by Android system when you start them using an `Intent`. We should not create `Activity` instances using its constructor.

In `spinnerSelects` class, the `spinnerInputChoice` you are trying use is not part of the `MainActivity`'s instance which was created by Android system. Because the instance of `spinnerSelects` you have created in `onItemSelected` method has different version of extended `MainActivity`.

***Update***

Check if following solve your problem:

1. Remove `MainActivity` inheritense from `spinnerSelects`.
2. In `onItemSelected`, supply `context` in `spinnerSelects` through constructor. You can use it to `getResources`.

```
public class spinnerSelects {
    private Context context;

    public spinnerSelects(Context pContext) {
        context = pContext;
    }

    // Your code

}
```

3. Change `setInputOutputSpinners` method's return type to `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>` and then return created `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>` instance.
4. In `onItemSelected` method set the returned adapter from `setInputOutputSpinners` to spinner.

Comment: I get your point. So, How Do I modify the classes? I tried to using constructor but they are creating much more problem

Comment: @ArifHamim I did not get your question. But check if updated answer solve your problem.